# Android: Short way to call widgets? Is eclipse the best?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-widget

I decided to learn a little bit android progrramming and **by using Eclipse + android plug-in** I made an android "hello world" application. After that I tryed something simple and **used 3 TextViews:**

```
ID:TextView1 String-Value:A=5
ID:TextView2 String-Value:B=10
ID:TextView3 String-Value:A+B=C=
```

I created them in **main.xml** menu by drag and drop so, to show them I'm using the flowing line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

**The Question is:** I want to get string values of **A** and **B** and append the result of 5+10 to the string value of **C** actualy I did it but it take too much codes just for get str value of a TextView and editing it. Is there any short way like in .Net?

```
string Str = This.Label1.Text();
```

And **is eclipse is the best IDE** or am I should use something else?
When I have several textviews etc, Why am I should write unnecessary lines if there is a short way to do it.

**Another Question** is I get str-value of **B** which is 10 but when I tryed the same thing for **A** it says there is nothing inside **VarAStr**
**My Codes are:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

TextView VarAStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.VarA);
TextView VarBStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.VarB);
TextView VarC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.VarC);

try{
    int VarA=Integer.parseInt(VarAStr.getText().toString().substring(2));
    int VarB=Integer.parseInt(VarBStr.getText().toString().substring(2));
    VarC.append(String.format("%d", (VarA+VarB)));
}
catch(Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString() + "   -" + VarAStr.getText().toString() + "-", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//Show(); 
}
```

For the last question I found a bad code line in main.xml :) wich has no **android:text="@string/VarA"** I added this and problem solved.

Thank you for any respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always put the repeated code on a function that returns a string.

Something like:

```
public String getTextOfView(int id) {
    TextView tmp = (TextView)findViewById(id);
    return tmp.getText.toString();
}
```